# Función async no funciona como pensaba

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

tengo un `.json` donde poseo un listado de turnos, el hecho es que necesito recorrerlo con Javascript por lo que lo primero que hago es llamarlo y guardarlo en una variable global `Dat`

```
async function Datos() {
    await $.getJSON("static/data.json",async function  (responseJSON) {
        Dat=await responseJSON
    });
}
Datos()
```

Hasta ahi todo perfecto, incluso si ejecuto esa función anda perfecto, el problema surge cuando la siguiente funcion necesita de la variable `Dat`, y la consola me dice que Dat no esta declarada, entiendo que Javascript continua ejecutando funciones, ¿pero no deberia detenerse en `Datos()` hasta que termine agregandole el async await?

```
function listaturnos(){
    Dat.forEach(element => {
        console.log('esta funcion anda')
    });
}
listaturnos();
```

Comment: si "**consola me dice que Dat no esta declarada**", es porque no esta declarada... Podrias mostrar el codigo completo, podrías haber olvidado declarar `Dat`

Comment: `Dat` está declarada dentro de la función `Datos( )`

Comment: No pues,.., si dices que es variable global y lo utilizas en varias funciones no debes declararla dentro de una funcion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async/await` se usa para evitar el uso de `callback` y hacer que tu código parezca "síncrono" gracias al keyword `await` que hace que la ejecución de la función se suspenda hasta que se haya resuelto lo que se este evaluando y volver a retomar la función donde se había pausado cuando se ha resuelto lo que se estaba evaluando.

En tu caso, estas mezclando ambos "paradigmas" de asincronia el de `callbacks` y `async/await`.

Si quieres tener los datos disponibles antes de que se ejecute `listaturnos` se debería esperar la función `Datos`.

El `await` no se puede usar en `global scope` siempre tiene que ir dentro de una función `async`, por lo tanto, tendrás que crear una función "wrapper" que inicie el get de los datos y  luego seguir con el código.

```js
var datos;
async function setDatos() {
 datos =  await $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
}

function listaturnos(){
    datos.forEach(element => {
        console.log('esta funcion anda', element)
    });
}

async function init() {
  await setDatos(); // se espera que acabe el get de datos y luego se sigue
  listaturnos();
}

init()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

He cambiado los nombres de la funciones, espero que no sea un problema.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, anda a la perfeccion, gracias por desburrarme